# How to iterate over a list that has duplicate values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory-management, list-comprehension

This is probably a very basic question but I dont know what I have to search for to find the answer for it:

I have this code:

```
list = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]

list.append(list[0])

for i in list:
    i.append(0)

print(list)
```

This List will later be used as coordinates for a curve. I need to duplicate the first coordinate at the end to get a closed curve.

If I then want to add a third value to each coordinate in the list the first and last item in list will be iterated over twice:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I am guessing they have the same memory address and thereby the append-function is applied to the same object at this address once for the first index and once for the last.

What is this phenomenon called ? what is the easiest way to get the list like this:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a list comprehension:

```
list = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]

list.append(list[0])
list = [x + [0] for x in list]

print(list)
# [[0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

**EDIT**: The trick here is, using `x + [0]` within the list comprehension. This way new lists are created, thus you do not append `0` to the same list twice (Hattip to @dx_over_dt)

The problem you have with your approach is, that the first and last element of your list refers to the very same object. You can see this, when you print `i` and `list` for every iteration:

```
for i in list:
     i.append(0)
     print(i)
     print(list)
```

So for the first and last `i` in your loop, you will append a `0` to the very same list.
You could stick to your approach appending a copy of the first element:

```
list.append(list[0].copy())
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I thought that list comprehension is simply a more efficient way of writing for-loops. But is the iteration done differently ?

Comment: Also, the list comprehension will generate new objects, that's why it is working properly.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much!

Comment: Afaik, it's only generating new objects because of the + operator. `[x for x in list]` I *believe* won't create new objects. If you had a function that appends an element and returns the list rather than using +, I believe you would have the same behavior as your for-loop. For that matter, your original for-loop could have done `for i in range(len(list)): list[i] = list[i] + [0]`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to add the 0's before appending the closing point.

```py
list = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]

for i in list:
    i.append(0)

list.append(list[0])

print(list)
```

It's the tiniest bit more efficient than a list comprehension because it's not making copies of the elements.

Comment: That is true, however, in my actual code, the append happens at a different location as I also need the coordinates without the third value but with the first item at the end.